# Cannot register service worker on react serverless

Tags: reactjs, scope, progressive-web-apps, github-pages, serverless

I am trying to register a service worker to make a react application PWA, when deployed on GitHub pages.

The error I am getting is:

**No matching service worker detected. You may need to reload the page, or check that the scope of the service worker for the current page encloses the scope and start URL from the manifest.**

This is the **manifest.json**:

```
  "short_name": "React App",
  "name": "Create React App Sample",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "favicon.ico",
      "sizes": "64x64 32x32 24x24 16x16",
      "type": "image/x-icon"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo192.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "192x192"
    },
    {
      "src": "logo512.png",
      "type": "image/png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    }
  ],
  "start_url": "https://[github-username].github.io/",
  "display": "standalone",
  "theme_color": "#000000",
  "background_color": "#ffffff"
}
```

In **packages.json**:

```
"homepage": "https://[githubid].github.io/[repository]",
```

Both service-worker.js and register-serviceWorker.js are located in **src** folder.

I have tried to build it locally and serve it with *npm serve*, and the browser identifies the service worker.

My belief is that the **scope** and **start url** are not ok configured in **manifest.json**.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the following to **manifest.json**:

```
  "start_url": "https://[gitHubId].github.io/",
  "scope": "/",
```

It now works.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same issue in dev. env. even tho i run the build with [serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) package .
The solution was to export **NODE_ENV=production** as environment variable.
or we can simply remove production condition in service worker registration file.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' && 'serviceWorker' in navigator)
```